# Why I can't set zoom level on google maps

Tags: html, iframe

Why I can't set zoom level,  I tried using &z=5 to write on the end of link, buy not working. Here is demo

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2830.0493437376044!2d20.460033515820356!3d44.8205593841789!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x475a7ab4f7ba19a5%3A0xf3cb8c583ee409d6!2sGagarin+Film!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sba!4v1472463205637&z=5" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9fdgfpn/154/

Answer (score 2):

If your embed code is coming from maps.google.com, the "pb" URL parameter contains every map setting in one long string, including the zoom level.

Each value in this parameter is separated by an exclamation mark, and begins with a 2-letter code. The first three values begin with "1m". The fourth value, beginning with "1d", is the zoom level. Change the value between "1d" and the exclamation mark to adjust the zoom level.

A value of around 1000 displays an area about the size of a city block, and a value above 400,000 will encompass the globe.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
    </script>

    <script>
    function initialize()
    {
      var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
        zoom:7,
        panControl:true,
        zoomControl:true,
        mapTypeControl:true,
        scaleControl:true,
        streetViewControl:true,
        overviewMapControl:true,
        rotateControl:true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```